# Multiple IP addresses to one NIC, but advanced IP settings window only shows one?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip

The ipconfig of my Windows Server 2003 server shows that the IP addresses 10.0.0.3, 10.0.0.11, and 10.0.0.12 are assigned to it. However, when I look in the Advanced TCP/IP Settings window for that connection, I only see the IP address of 10.0.0.3 listed there.

In the Support tab for the connection, it shows that it's connected through 10.0.0.12, and in the Support > Details window, it shows all the previously mentioned IP addresses.

Where are these phantom IP addresses being stored and how can I free them up so I don't have any IP conflicts?

Comment: I failed to mention this but the server was part of a SQL cluster, so 10.0.0.11 and 10.0.0.12 were the cluster group IP addresses. Found it under the Cluster Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Nic's that are used in Clustering (whether MSCS or MSNLB) MUST have multiple IP's bound to them. These virtual IP's are always listed in the appropriate role's MMC Snap-in (Cluster Admin for MSCS and NLB Manager in MSNLB). All IP's are listed in the Advanced TAB for TCP/IP Settings of any NIC's involved in a cluster:

(right-click the interface-->properties-->(double-click 'Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)')-->advanced-->(look in the IP addresses window)

It's on you to determine what IP's are available before binding them to a clustered node. Keep an Excel spreadsheet with a workbook for each subnet in your LAN...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the leases of the DHCP server.  In windows DHCP servers, it will accept a description field.  (Just in case, to get there: Start -> Admin Tools -> DHCP , then expand server -> expand scope -> click Address Leases)

Depending on the function of your server, it might actually be using the separate IPs.  RRAS is notorious for this.